# Automated driver testing tool for Android and Windoows

Tags: android, windows, driver, automated-tests

I want to write an automated driver testing tool for both Windows7/8 and Android.
I want to share as much as I can between the two OSs.

Do you have an idea what the best system is to write this automated tests and what the language is to write it in?

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give more information?  I'm very confused as to what this question is asking.  Are you looking for an automation framework for existing tests (in which case, please share what language(s) are they written in, how tightly coupled are they between platforms, etc)?  Or are you looking for help writing tests that can be automated (in which case, please describe the tests are you trying to write at the very least)?  Either way, it would be very helpful for you to give an overview of what your drivers do and what you hope to achieve through testing.

Answer (score 1):

For Android, all its drivers are the same as for embedded Linux, so look no further than the Linux drivers repositories.

If you'd like to mess around with that stuff, I'd suggest you take a look at Python. Most drivers are written in C/C++, but that doesn't mean you'd be forced to use C/C++ to test them if what you're looking for is just black box testing.